# Using a capacitor to drive Nema 23

Tags: capacitor, dc-motor, stepper-motor

Can anyone tell me if I can use a capacitor to drive a Nema 23 stepper motor? Looking for a cheap and crude solution without using a driver or controller. If so, help with what capacitor and how to wire would be amazing for 24v DC circuit.

(Background is that I have the motor, and it suits the c-beam assembly I am using to make a TV lifter. I don’t want to swap for standard DC motor. I don’t need to control steps or speed, just fwd and reverse for which I pan to use a relay)

Thanks
David

Comment: No, you can't. Buy a self-contained stepper driver, many available on online market-places. That's the cheapest and crudest that will work. Some don't need an MCU to drive, just switch closures or voltages on pins.

Comment: You’re confusing a stepper motor with an induction motor with capacitor start/run.